# How to implement string whitin a string in SQL

Tags: html, css, sql, sql-server

It's one of the pain that non-English language web designers comprehend:

Imagine I have a cell that it's value is `'450\k\200'`, as you see `k` is placed in between since it's an English character but if it's `'450\ک\200'` the non-English `ک` character is shown in the right which is a problem about non-English languages.

I can apply a trick and insert it inside `table`, `tr`, `td` tags like this:

```
<table><tr>
<td>450\</td><td>ک</td><td>\200<td>
</tr></table>
```

which works.
The question is about the query, how can I split text by `\` character then implement related tags as the format I just mentioned?
I thought something like following can be used:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG( (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT ( '450\k\200' , '\' )) , ',')
```

But I get the error saying: 
`Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

How can I deal with this weird problem? I appreciate if you suggest any trick other than `table` tag, I even tried `pre` or `code` tags but even it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear, sorry. Are you trying to solve an SQL problem with HTML? But by the looks of it, it's more likely a Unicode BIDI problem.

Comment: Correct syntax is `SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ',') FROM STRING_SPLIT('450\k\200', '\' )`. Note, that `STRING_SPLIT` doesn't quarantee the order of the substrings.

Comment: I tried to enlighten the matter, I found a trick to handle the problem by using `table`, `tr` and `td` tags when I want to show it manually, but the question is about when it's populated by the query result, how to change the query result so that the cell value be formatted as I mentioned?

Comment: @Zhorov  Thanks, you are right, but how to implement `table`, `tr` and `td` tags then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Zhorov who pointed to the solution, I completed the query and it worked, here is the query:

```
    SELECT '<table><tr>' + STRING_AGG('<td>' + value +'</td>', '') + '</tr></table>'
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(N'450\ک\200', '\' );
```

Comment: Consider simple replacement: `SELECT CONCAT('<table><tr><td>', REPLACE('450\k\200', '\', '</td><td>'), '</td></tr></table>')
`

Comment: @ Zhorov, +1, amazing solution, you didn't use `STRING_AGG()` and `STRING_SPLIT()` functions and you achieved the same result just by utilizing `CONCAT()` and `REPLACE()` functions, although it seems a little bit confusing plus since I don't want to remove backslash in the result, I prefer this one: `SELECT CONCAT('<table><tr><td>', REPLACE('450\k\200', '\', '\</td><td>'), '</td></tr></table>')`